# Gmail contacts API limitations workaround

Tags: java, google-contacts-api

Given that the Google Contacts java API [has not exposed all the fields](http://groups.google.com/group/google-contacts-api/browse_thread/thread/a2dbc7d052fa318b/f704527adc6c6597?lnk=gst&q=exposed#f704527adc6c6597), how would you workaround the problem of accessing the 'Mr' or 'Company' fields on the Google Contacts api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very familiar with the Contacts API, but it appears that newer versions of the API show more data. Which version are you currently using? You can find the migration guide here: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/migration_guide.html

A different approach could be to copy your data to a different field, using a batch process. Maybe you can access the data that way. http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/gdata/batch.html